# How clear all forms and open a new one in Firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Let's suppose the user is navigating throughout an Android/iOS app and open the following forms:

`Form A --> Form B --> Form C`

In `Form C` he press a button to logout from the app. This should clear all the previous forms (including `Form C`) and open a new Form (`Signin Form D`).

So it would be something like that:

1. `Form A --> Form B --> Form C --> Press Logout Button`
2. Close `Form A`, `B` and `C`
3. Open `Form D`
4. Now if the user press the back button in `Form D` the app will be closed because there are no more forms in the task.

I tried to open `Form D` and close previous ones but it didn't freed completely the previous forms. Anyway to achieve this for Android/iOS?

Comment: Please show the code where you *open `FormD` and close previous ones*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid this won't work exactly as you imagined. Why?

In Delphi application the first form that is created becomes [Application MainForm](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/FMX.Forms.TApplication.MainForm). Closing this form then closes the entire application.

Now in your case you say that the `Form A` is the first form that is opened meaning that it automatically becomes the `MainForm` of your application. Thus closing it will close your application.

So in order to achieve what you want you will have to make sure that your `Form D` is actually the first form that is created in your application.

Comment: In FireMonkey, the `Application.MainForm` can be reassigned dynamically, as it is a public writable property. The same is not true in VCL. So FormA can be the initial MainForm, and then FormD can become the new MainForm when releasing FormA

Comment: @RemyLebeau Not acording to documentation. Acording to documentation `MainForm cannot be modified at run time (it is read-only at run time)`

Comment: You can also create a hidden MainForm, which you never show. Then that can be your base form to work from.

Comment: @SilverWarior the documentation is wrong. FMX's `MainForm` can be changed dynamically: `procedure TApplication.SetMainForm(const Value: TCommonCustomForm); begin if FMainForm <> Value then begin FMainForm := Value; TMessageManager.DefaultManager.SendMessage(Self, TMainFormChangedMessage.Create(FMainForm)); end; end;`

Comment: You say: *...the first form that is created becomes Application.MainForm*. That is true only if it is created via `Application.CreateForm()`, not if it is created via e.g. `TForm1.Create()`. The other thing is that `FMX` mainform *can be changed* during runtime. The documentation (checked for XE7 and Rio) is wrong on this point. Just tested it successfully in XE7.

Answer (score 1):

@SilverWarior was indeed correct. The problem was that `Form A` kept always being the `ApplicationMainForm`, therefore it couldn't be closed. However, as @Remy Labeau and @Tom Brunberg said. The `MainForm` can be changed during application runtime.

To deal with this problem I used the code below. Suppose I am in `Form A` and I want navigate to `Form B` and close previous form.

```
if not Assigned(frmFinanceiro) then
  frmFinanceiro := TfrmFinanceiro.Create(Application);
Application.MainForm := frmFinanceiro;
frmFinanceiro.Show;
Close;
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you fix that?

Can use on next:

```
procedure TfrmMain.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = vkHardwareBack then
  begin
    Key := 0;
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Yes, I fixed that at the time with @SilverWarrior answer and Remy Lebeau commnent.